# Closing PySpark notebook properly

Tags: ipython, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter notebook with PySpark, which uses Spark as a kernel.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to properly close it and I have an impression that something keeps hanging, as the memory on the driver on which the notebook is running gets full and crashes (I get GC overhead exception).

I'm closing the whole thing by simply killing the notebook using the process id which I save to .pid file. But I have a feeling that the following state is note good:

[image: problem]

What is the actual problem and how to solve it, that is, how the close the whole thing (on driver and on the yarn) properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "File" -> "Close and halt" inside Jupyter. This will close spark context and kill yarn containers from the session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And is there any difference in what I'm doing?

Comment: I'm not sure, using jupyter menu always works in my environment, even if driver gets out of memory exceptions. Maybe you are killing the wrong process?

Comment: I think not. But do you have any idea what kind of problem I am experiencing? Because these spark shell instances seem to be accumulating even if I haven't shutdown the notebook, that is, during the work they accumulate and at the end I get GC overhead error shown in spark ui.